# Spider Engine on Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, web-crawler, galera

I want to use the Spider Plugin on Galera nodes. I cannot find any documentation or use cases about that kind of usage. What are the drawbacks if any for such a case? I will be happy if someone use it that way to share experience.

I installed the plugin with some errors:

```
INSTALL SONAME "ha_spider";
2022-11-24 11:52:01 23 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_one_table`(tab_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    test_col_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    _sql text charset utf8 collate utf8_bin)
begin  set @col_exists := 0;  select 1 into @col_exists from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql'      AND TABLE_NAME = tab_name      AND COLUMN_NAME = test_col_name;  if @col_exists = 0 then    select @stmt := _sql;    prepare sp_stmt1 from @stmt;    execute sp_stmt1;  end if;end', Internal MariaDB error code: 1959
2022-11-24 11:52:01 23 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_one_table`(tab_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    test_col_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    _sql text charset utf8 collate utf8_bin)
begin  set @col_exists := 0;  select 1 into @col_exists from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql'      AND TABLE_NAME = tab_name      AND COLUMN_NAME = test_col_name;  if @col_exists = 0 then    select @stmt := _sql;    prepare sp_stmt1 from @stmt;    execute sp_stmt1;  end if;end', Error_code: 1959
2022-11-24 11:52:01 35 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_system_tables`()
begin  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 2), '-', -1)    into @server_name;  if @server_name regexp '^[0-9]+$' then    select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 3), '-', -1)      into @server_name;  end if;  select substring_index(version(), '.', 1)    into @server_major_version;  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '.', 2), '.', -1)    into @server_minor_version;  call mysql.spider_fix_one_table('spider_tables', 'server',   'alter table mysql.spider_tables    add server char(64) default null,    add scheme char(64) default null,    add host char(64) default null,    add port char(5) default null,    add socket char(64) default null,    add username char(64) default null,    add password char(64) default null,    add tgt_db_name char(64) default null,    add tgt_table_name char(64) default null');  select COLU
2022-11-24 11:52:01 35 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_system_tables`()
begin  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 2), '-', -1)    into @server_name;  if @server_name regexp '^[0-9]+$' then    select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 3), '-', -1)      into @server_name;  end if;  select substring_index(version(), '.', 1)    into @server_major_version;  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '.', 2), '.', -1)    into @server_minor_version;  call mysql.spider_fix_one_table('spider_tables', 'server',   'alter table mysql.spider_tables    add server char(64) default null,    add scheme char(64) default null,    add host char(64) default null,    add port char(5) default null,    add socket char(64) default null,    add username char(64) default null,    add password char(64) default null,    add tgt_db_name char(64) default null,    add tgt_table_name char(64) default null');  select
2022-11-24 11:52:01 29 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_one_table`(tab_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    test_col_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    _sql text charset utf8 collate utf8_bin)
begin  set @col_exists := 0;  select 1 into @col_exists from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql'      AND TABLE_NAME = tab_name      AND COLUMN_NAME = test_col_name;  if @col_exists = 0 then    select @stmt := _sql;    prepare sp_stmt1 from @stmt;    execute sp_stmt1;  end if;end', Internal MariaDB error code: 1959
2022-11-24 11:52:01 29 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_one_table`(tab_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    test_col_name char(255) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin,    _sql text charset utf8 collate utf8_bin)
begin  set @col_exists := 0;  select 1 into @col_exists from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql'      AND TABLE_NAME = tab_name      AND COLUMN_NAME = test_col_name;  if @col_exists = 0 then    select @stmt := _sql;    prepare sp_stmt1 from @stmt;    execute sp_stmt1;  end if;end', Error_code: 1959
2022-11-24 11:52:01 8 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_system_tables`()
begin  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 2), '-', -1)    into @server_name;  if @server_name regexp '^[0-9]+$' then    select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 3), '-', -1)      into @server_name;  end if;  select substring_index(version(), '.', 1)    into @server_major_version;  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '.', 2), '.', -1)    into @server_minor_version;  call mysql.spider_fix_one_table('spider_tables', 'server',   'alter table mysql.spider_tables    add server char(64) default null,    add scheme char(64) default null,    add host char(64) default null,    add port char(5) default null,    add socket char(64) default null,    add username char(64) default null,    add password char(64) default null,    add tgt_db_name char(64) default null,    add tgt_table_name char(64) default null');  select COLU
2022-11-24 11:52:01 8 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_fix_system_tables`()
begin  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 2), '-', -1)    into @server_name;  if @server_name regexp '^[0-9]+$' then    select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '-', 3), '-', -1)      into @server_name;  end if;  select substring_index(version(), '.', 1)    into @server_major_version;  select substring_index(substring_index(version(), '.', 2), '.', -1)    into @server_minor_version;  call mysql.spider_fix_one_table('spider_tables', 'server',   'alter table mysql.spider_tables    add server char(64) default null,    add scheme char(64) default null,    add host char(64) default null,    add port char(5) default null,    add socket char(64) default null,    add username char(64) default null,    add password char(64) default null,    add tgt_db_name char(64) default null,    add tgt_table_name char(64) default null');  select
[ERROR] PROCEDURE mysql.spider_fix_one_table does not exist
2022-11-24 11:52:01 22 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_fix_one_table does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_fix_one_table', Internal MariaDB error code: 1305
2022-11-24 11:52:01 22 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_fix_one_table does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_fix_one_table', Error_code: 1305
2022-11-24 11:52:01 42 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_fix_system_tables does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_fix_system_tables', Internal MariaDB error code: 1305
2022-11-24 11:52:01 42 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_fix_system_tables does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_fix_system_tables', Error_code: 1305
2022-11-24 11:52:01 24 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_plugin_installer`()
begin  set @win_plugin := IF(@@version_compile_os like 'Win%', 1, 0);  set @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin := 0;  select @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin := 1    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.plugins    where PLUGIN_NAME = 'SPIDER_ALLOC_MEM';  set @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin := 0;  select @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin := 1 from mysql.plugin    where name = 'spider_alloc_mem';  if @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin = 0 then    if @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin = 1 then      /*        spider_alloc_mem plugin is present in mysql.plugin but not in        information_schema.plugins. Remove spider_alloc_mem plugin entry        in mysql.plugin first.      */      delete from mysql.plugin where name = 'spider_alloc_mem';    end if;    if @win_plugin = 0 then       install plugin spider_alloc_mem soname 'ha_spider.so';    else      install plugin spider_alloc_mem soname
2022-11-24 11:52:01 24 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'Invalid role specification ``' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `mysql`.`spider_plugin_installer`()
begin  set @win_plugin := IF(@@version_compile_os like 'Win%', 1, 0);  set @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin := 0;  select @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin := 1    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.plugins    where PLUGIN_NAME = 'SPIDER_ALLOC_MEM';  set @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin := 0;  select @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin := 1 from mysql.plugin    where name = 'spider_alloc_mem';  if @have_spider_i_s_alloc_mem_plugin = 0 then    if @have_spider_alloc_mem_plugin = 1 then      /*        spider_alloc_mem plugin is present in mysql.plugin but not in        information_schema.plugins. Remove spider_alloc_mem plugin entry        in mysql.plugin first.      */      delete from mysql.plugin where name = 'spider_alloc_mem';    end if;    if @win_plugin = 0 then       install plugin spider_alloc_mem soname 'ha_spider.so';    else      install plugin spider_alloc_mem s
2022-11-24 11:52:01 30 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_plugin_installer does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_plugin_installer', Internal MariaDB error code: 1305
2022-11-24 11:52:01 30 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error 'PROCEDURE mysql.spider_plugin_installer does not exist' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop procedure mysql.spider_plugin_installer', Error_code: 1305
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT ENGINE, SUPPORT FROM information_schema.ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+
| ENGINE             | SUPPORT |
+--------------------+---------+
| SPIDER             | YES     |
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     |
| MEMORY             | YES     |
| Aria               | YES     |
| MyISAM             | YES     |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     |
| CSV                | YES     |
+--------------------+---------+
```

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show tables;
+------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql                    |
+------------------------------------+
| column_stats                       |
| columns_priv                       |
| db                                 |
| event                              |
| func                               |
| general_log                        |
| global_priv                        |
| gtid_slave_pos                     |
| help_category                      |
| help_keyword                       |
| help_relation                      |
| help_topic                         |
| index_stats                        |
| innodb_index_stats                 |
| innodb_table_stats                 |
| plugin                             |
| proc                               |
| procs_priv                         |
| proxies_priv                       |
| roles_mapping                      |
| servers                            |
| slow_log                           |
| spider_link_failed_log             |
| spider_link_mon_servers            |
| spider_table_crd                   |
| spider_table_position_for_recovery |
| spider_table_sts                   |
| spider_tables                      |
| spider_xa                          |
| spider_xa_failed_log               |
| spider_xa_member                   |
| table_stats                        |
| tables_priv                        |
| time_zone                          |
| time_zone_leap_second              |
| time_zone_name                     |
| time_zone_transition               |
| time_zone_transition_type          |
| transaction_registry               |
| user                               |
| wsrep_cluster                      |
| wsrep_cluster_members              |
| wsrep_streaming_log                |
+------------------------------------+
```

After that the spider engine and table are working as expected so far. But the thing that worry me is there is not one use case like that.

Comment: Is each leg of the Spider a Galera cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Galera cluster at the moment really supports only InnoDB. This fact is documented on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/. DDL on Spider tables may (or may not) work but at the moment not recommended.